# Elasticsearch collapse a field based on keywords field with case insensitive and ignore punctuation matching

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

I would like to collapse a field in Elasticsearch to group documents with the same title. Collapse would only work on a keyword field, so I added a multi-field that uses a keyword type. The grouping works, but I would like to make it a little bit more flexible by removing extra whitespace, punctuation and lowercase when the keyword field gets indexed. I was able to solve the lowercase problem by using the lowercase normalizer as part of my mapping, but I'm having trouble with the punctuation. My goal would be to have something like these 2 titles match.

> "China steps up African economic, trade ties to compete with US\'
> ‘game changing\' moves 'China steps up African economic, trade ties
> to compete with US’ ‘game changing’ moves

They would both be indexed as

> 'china steps up african economic trade ties to compete with us game
> changing moves'

on the keyword field.

Here is an example of my mapping on the title field. Do keep in mind that you can't collapse on a text field, so it must be done on the keyword multifield part of the document.

```
"title": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "title_collapse": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to successfully group articles with mismatched casing by using the 'lowercase' normalizer, but not having luck with the punctuation/whitespace